# Wordpress the_content() Selectively displaying or hiding "Read More"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Per the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content), I was able to remove the "Read More" link on my home page's post list by using

```
<?php the_content('',TRUE,''); ?>
```

Most of our posts link to external articles and thus are maybe only a sentence or two (no need to *Read More* as it were). If, however, we do write a longer post, I may want that "Read More" to appear. I can choose what is in the excerpt and the rest of the content by using `<!--more-->` when writing a post. To get a custom "Read More" link, I add

```
<?php the_content('Read More',TRUE,''); ?>
```

But when I do this, "Read More" *always* appears. Is there a way to selectively show this *only if* there is content below a `<!--more-->` comment in the post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_extended()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended) . It returns an array with two keys `main` and `extended`. You can check whether the `extended` key contains anything and display the "read more" link if it does.

Note that you must pass the post's content as an argument when calling the function.